M3 Pro Fans are not running.. or running super slow
Today I was doing some load tasks, and I am at 90C on cpu and 87C on gpu... but the fans are only at 2000rpm.. whats happening? how can I fix this? Or should I say, is this normal? I read other posts but everything just says 'wait for it to heat up'... this is 90C
It even hit 97C and no fan change, its stuck at ~2,000rpm and I dont even hear fan noise.


Welcome to Ask Different. Does your MacBook Pro feel hot? Where do the stats come from?

@jaume sorry for late reply, yes it does feel hot.... and its coming from iStat Menu

Thermal management on Apple Silicon computers tend to prioritize quietness over coolness (according to marketing material from Apple and from anecdotal conversations with Mac owners), and your post seems to confirms it.

There are apps that help you control fan activity, a quick search returned Mac Fan Control https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download (mentioned here:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253563212?sortBy=rank). You may want to give it a try. If you want to get temps from another app (to corroborate iStat's values), check Hot: https://github.com/macmade/Hot (mentioned here: https://osxdaily.com/2023/06/21/get-temperature-apple-silicon-mac/).
